# Border effect outside the element

Tags: html, css

[image: Light gray outline gradient outside the gray border]

Hello I want to set the light gray outline outside gray border line just like in the following image.either there is a border position set or blur effect the input text.
Please tell me how can I fix this issue? I am doing all of this in css.

```css
.container {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea,
textarea.form-control {
  background-color: #efeeef;
  width: 396px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #cecece;
}

textarea.form-control {
  line-height: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--Form element-->
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Enter Your email" class="form-email form-control textarea border-color outline" id="form-email">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
```

When I am using shade effects it is also useless.Is there any way to set the position of the border in this input area.

Comment: Looks like `box-shadow` to me.

Comment: Any reason not to use a [box shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borders cannot be set to blur (at least directly). If you are using some sort of CSS library, say Bootstrap then it may be adding `box-shadow` to the input elements.

Setting the `box-shadow: none;` on the required input should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert but try

```
form{
         border: 1px(thickness) outset(type of border) grey(color)

     }
```

for more information go to this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp